# Python How to create multiple values against a single key in dictionary

Tags: python, data-structures

[Python, datastructres] How to create multiple values against a single key in dictionary like below

```
main_dict = { 'stats': IP_dict_name_1, 'Add': IP_dict_name_2}  
IP_dict_name_1 = {uniq_ip_1 : [time, threshold_counter], unique_ip_2: [time, threshold_counter]}  
IP_dict_name_1 = {uniq_ip_1 : [time, threshold_counter], unique_ip_2: [time, threshold_counter]}
```

Actually I want to create a data structure in which we can log commands like the above scenario. Forexample if 'stats' command is already inserted to dictionary then it does not insert it again in the dictionary if not present then create the data structure above. I am confused how to do that in an efficent way. Inshort, I want to keep track of each remote_ip who executed the command and set the threshold of command i.e 5 if he wants to execute 'stats' command more than 3 times in a hour then it is not allowed to do so. Can anyone help to do so. Any rough idea is appreciated?

Comment: Can you also add expected input and output in the question

Comment: If you really want to be able to check whether a command was executed more than *k* times by a given ip *in the last 60 minutes*, the appropriate data structure is to maintain a **queue** of the last executions of that command by that ip. However, before you move on to that, I suggest solving a simplified problem where hours are not "sliding" but at fixed intervals (1pm-2pm; 2pm-3pm; etc). This way you only need to maintain a **count** of the number of executions in the last window, and reset the count everytime we change windows.

Comment: @Stef Yes, I am able to solve the problem for tracing of IP in specificed interval. I can solve it like that {IP:[first_log_time, thresholdof_cmd_execution]}. I am confuse how to maintain this list independtly for every unique command

Comment: @Zahid Instead of using the ip as the key in this dictionary, use a pair (command, ip) as the pair.

Comment: @Stef in that case, I think that our program efficency will suffer bcz for every execution we are inserting command unnecessarily. We have fixed commands which user can execute. what do you think

Comment: In that case you can have a set of existing command names, and add a check that the command name exists. Raise an error without adding anything to the dictionary if the user tries a command which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pairs `(command, ip)` as the keys to your dictionary of logs.

In addition, I recommend the excellent [dictionary method `dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

```py
exec_logs = {}
threshold_per_hour = 3

def exec_command(command_name, ip, current_hour):
  previous_hour, n = exec_logs.setdefault((command_name, ip), (current_hour, 0))
  if previous_hour == current_hour:
    if n >= threshold_per_hour:
      print('Command aborted: User {} cannot execute command {} more than {} times per hour.'.format(ip, command_name, threshold_per_hour))
      return # do not execute command
    else:
      exec_logs[(command_name, ip)] = (current_hour, n+1)
      print('Command {} successfully executed.'.format(command_name))
  else:
    exec_logs[(command_name, ip)] = (current_hour, 1)
    print('Command {} successfully executed.'.format(command_name))
```

Testing:

```py
>>> exec_command('make coffee', 127, '1pm')
Command make coffee successfully executed.
>>> exec_command('make coffee', 127, '1pm')
Command make coffee successfully executed.
>>> exec_command('make coffee', 127, '1pm')
Command make coffee successfully executed.
>>> exec_command('make coffee', 127, '1pm')
Command aborted: User 127 cannot execute command make coffee more than 3 times per hour.
>>> exec_logs
{('make coffee', 127): ('1pm', 3)}
>>> exec_command('make coffee', 127, '2pm')
Command make coffee successfully executed.
>>> exec_logs
{('make coffee', 127): ('2pm', 1)}
>>> exec_command('make coffee', 139, '2pm')
Command make coffee successfully executed.
>>> exec_command('make coffee', 139, '2pm')
Command make coffee successfully executed.
>>> exec_command('make coffee', 139, '2pm')
Command make coffee successfully executed.
>>> exec_logs
{('make coffee', 127): ('2pm', 1), ('make coffee', 139): ('2pm', 3)}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can check if the key already exists in `main_dict` with `if "stats" not in main_dict`, just replace "stats" with what ever key you want to check against. Here is a simple snippet:

```
command = {
    "uniq_ip_1" : ["time", "threshold_counter"],
    "unique_ip_2": ["time", "threshold_counter"]}

main_dict = {}

if "stats" not in main_dict:
    main_dict["stats"] = command

print(main_dict)

if "stats" not in main_dict:
    main_dict["stats"] = command

print(main_dict)
```